# phonegap android app only showing connecting to device

Tags: android, cordova

I AM creating a phonegap android app. I am creating this app using help of [this tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/). When i am istalling this app on device its onDeviceReady function is not working. It is only showing coneecting to device. My onDeviceReady function is below:-

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    alert('device ready');
    try {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        pushNotification.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,{"senderID":"41327727848","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
    } catch (ex) {
        alert('error: ' + ex);
    }
},
```

It does not alert anything. I can't find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the suggestions you can try:

- make sure you have added cordova.js into your html file.
- deviceready function should be called after cordova.js is loaded.

the link you've provided is using old version version of plugin.([link-old plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)).I advice you to follow the new one which is [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)